# Map JSON object to TypeScript object automatically (Angular 2)

Tags: json, dictionary, typescript, angular2-services

i'm new to Typescript and javascript.
My question is: 
how from this

```

```
{
    "release": {
        "ref": {},
        "commits": {}
    },
    "debug": {
        "ref": {},
        "commits": {}
    },
    "feature": {
        "ref": {},
        "commits": {}
    },
    "hotfix": {
        "ref": {},
        "commits": {}
    }
}
```

```

map it with with Typescript using interfaces

`export interface IRepo {
    branches: IBranch; // how to make branches a of type string: IBranch dictionary? 
}`

there will be unknown number of properties like debug, release, etc, 
i want to keep them as dictionary in IRepo instance

i'm using this to fetch data:

```

```
getRepo() : Observable<IRepo> {
    if (!this.repo) {
        return this.http.get(this._baseUrl + 'repo.json')
            .map((res: Response) => {
                this.repo = res.json();
                return this.repo;
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
    } else {
        return this.createObservable(this.repo);
    }
}
```

```

Comment: What are the types of the properties? If you don't need them strongly typed, you can just iterate over the properties of the object with for-in.  If you need each of them strongly typed at compile time, can you specify what type(s) they'll have (if anything in common)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a map that goes from some *known* `string` to an object of known structure (has `ref` `commits`). Just use a string indexer:

```
interface BranchByName {
  [branchName: string]: {
    ref: any;
    commits: any;
  } 
}
```